# In Magento, Will the guest users have their products in cart in the Abandoned carts in admin section

Tags: magento

In Magento if a user is checking out as a guest user with products in his shopping cart, and at certain point he leaves the checkout process before completion. will the products in his shopping cart will be shown in the "Abandoned carts" in Magento admin panel?

thanks
Balan

Comment: No. Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by testing it myself..

Answer : No, the products in guest users shopping cart will not be shown in the "Abandoned cart" option in the backend. This will show only the abandoned products in shopping cart of registered users only.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as correct to help other stackoverflow users.

Comment: Ok thanks for informing.. however it would take 18 hours for me to accept my own answer..